# unable to access SharePoint Columns through Web Services

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

What are the Columns that are added within a Web part in the Site itself called when you are trying to get it back in the Web Service? I have a recently added column that is Yes or No for the answer. When i return the list GetListitems(), I get the item, but i do not see it as an attribute/ How does one access this data? is it it some sort of ViewField? Or FieldType? Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom columns need to be added using the viewFields property:

```
var viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"ViewFields","");
viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name='Field1' /><FieldRef Name='Field2'/>";

var result = listsvc.GetListItems("List_Name", null, ndQuery, viewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);
```

More info on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (full sample there)

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that the columns that don't have defaults and are thus empty if no value is set, will NOT show up in your CAML